# How do I make a column inside select option in HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, codeigniter-3

So, I have a select option HTML where the data is got from `json_decode(file_get_contents("myAPI.com"))` and it looked like this:

[image: select option HTML]

> note : the `-` is how I divide each data manually.

As you can see, the result is not neat, so tight, and hard to read.

I've tried using Javascript like this :

```
var spacesToAdd = 5; 
var biggestLength = 0; 
$("#pks_bank option").each(function(){ var len = $(this).text().length;
        if(len > biggestLength){
            biggestLength = len;
        } }); var padLength = biggestLength + spacesToAdd; 
$("#pks_bank option").each(function(){
            var parts = $(this).text().split('+');
            var strLength = parts[0].length;
            for(var x=0; x<(padLength-strLength); x++){
                parts[0] = parts[0]+' '; 
            }
            $(this).text(parts[0].replace(/ /g, '\u00a0')+'+'+parts[1]).text; });
```

But the result is getting worse and farther like this :
[image: select option with JS]

Below is my select option code :

```
<select name='pks_bank' id='pks_bank' data-widget='select2' class='multisel' 
        style='width:65%; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;'>
<option value='no'>- Pilih PKS Bank - </option>
    <?php
    foreach ($list_pks_bank as $data) {
       $id_wok = $data->PKS1 . '/' . $data->PKS2 . '/' . $data->PKS3 . '/' . $data->PKS4;
       $wok = $data->NMBNK . ' - ' . $data->NOPKS1  . ' - ' . $data->NOPKS2;
       echo "<option value='" . $data->PKS2 . "'>" . ucwords(strtoupper($wok)) . "</option>";
       }
    ?>
 </select>
```

How do I make a column inside select option in HTML/PHP? So it would be like this :

[image: combo box with column]

In .NET I can give the Combo Box `Column > ListBoxColumn` property

Comment: _"How do I make a column inside select option in HTML/PHP? "_ - you don't, because that is not possible with a native `select` element. If you want something that looks like that last picture, then you will have to create it out of other HTML elements yourself, that are suitable to create such a structure/display, and then add "select functionality" to it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the tittle correction. Really? Cant even using JS/Jquery or something?

Comment: `option` elements can contain plain text only, you can not insert any HTML elements into them, to create any such structure. So if doing it via markers/spacing in the text itself doesn't produce a satisfying enough result for you (using a monospace font would be the first thing you should do though, when going down that road), then you will have to build some alternative yourself.

Comment: That's kinda hard I think. You sure there is no alternative beside creating new structure/display?

Comment: Yes, there is no alternative. Of course there may be existing plugins you can find online which have already tried to solve this fairly common problem - sometimes people want to put images in there, or multiple columns, or whatever. Select2 is one I can think of off the top of my head, you can Google around to find others and see if they can help with your requirements